# Calculation of leakage current

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

I would like to know is there is a way to calculate (estimate) the leakage current for a diode?

Comment: What info do you have to make the estimation? Manufacturers publish datasheets of the devices they offer and leakage current is usually informed there.

Comment: I would like to know the general formula?

Comment: The 'saturation current' article in Wikipedia has a common formula frequently used in courses of semiconductor devices. Is this what you are looking for?https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_current